# how to display multiple plots(linecharts) in android using achartengine?

Tags: android, android-layout, plot, achartengine

i am new to programming and hence android programming.
I'm making an android app in which i have to show eeg data graphically (I mean dynamically in which data is received constantly and the graph is updated constantly with new values added to the right and the graph of old values moving to left and eventually out of view). now I could show 1 plot at a time but it would be really nice if I could show all plots (total 14) on a single screen from top to bottom. Now 14 charts may not be viewable at once, so i could add the function of scrolling so that some charts are visible at a time and others can be seen by scolling up or down.
 I am using AChartengine for plotting. Is there some way to display multiple plots on a single screen from top to bottom with scrolling? Thanks for giving ur time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess that, even if you could use a `ScrollView` to put many charts on same Activity/screen, it would be too heavy and chaotic. Why don't you multiplex data using different dataset for each graph? In this way you could have only some chart to display and data comparaison would be more intuitive...

You can make reference to "average temperature" inside achartengine examples, to know how to **put different series** (datasets) inside same chart.

Anyway, if you really want to create a 'long' scrolling screen with 14 charts, simply use a `ScrollView` like this:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:id="@+id/ScrollViewChartContainer" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">

 <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/trendchart" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:background="@android:color/transparent" android:orientation="horizontal" /> 
 <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/trendchart2" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:background="@android:color/transparent" android:orientation="horizontal" /> 
 ...
</ScrollView>
```

I have not tested such a layout, but it should work.